# Scope for reservation system

Tags: scope

I'm building a reservation system and would appreciate your thoughts on the best way to tackle this.  There bookable 'slots' every day (from 7am - 1pm & 2pm - 7pm).  I'm making the application in jQuery/Laravel and have already build the part which reserves the slot.  The slot should be reserved for a maximum of 15 mins.  After this time, if the booking has not been confirmed, then the slot should become available again.

What is the best way for me to check if the reserved spot has expired?  I have a number of ideas:

1) Insert a `expires_at` timestamp in the database when the slot becomes reserved.  Then have a cron job run every minute to see if the slot has expired.  If so, change the status back to Available.

2) Alternatively have a jQuery on page timer which starts as soon as the slot is reserved.  As soon as it hits 15 mins, send an ajax request to set the status back to 'Available' again.

Does anyone have any further suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Number 2 will not be recommended solution as the slot will not be available again if the browser is closed.

Comment: Yes that is true.  So the cron job would be required in this solution as well.

Comment: Yes, cron will be required in this solution.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions or do you think number 1 is the best?

Comment: This type of problem happens on all type of reservation systems like of hotels, so you have to research what they are doing and find out the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a cron job, you could make it part of the query.

[show records where status is not "confirmed" and expires_at > 15 minutes old]

You would show all these records as "open" to the user.

Comment: This would not work as the slot only gets reserved once the user clicks reserve.   This means the expires_at only gets added when they reserve the spot.

Comment: Step 1: User A reserves a spot which marks the spot in DB with expires_at with time +15 minutes from now.
Step 2: User A fails to confirm reservation within 15 minutes and spot becomes available for others.
Step 3: User B wants to see what is available.  Show all DB records where status is not "confirmed" and expires_at < current time

Bottom line: It can be done without cron job if structured correctly.